# Can I specify which VCS module or adaptor is used by a Luntbuild buiulder or schedule?

Tags: continuous-integration, luntbuild

I have luntbuild set up and working great for my project, with several different builder schedules running on trunk.  Now, I just created a branch, and I want to add at least one schedule (and corresponding builder, if necessary) to build that branch (I want the branch built separately from trunk).

Is this possible?  Some others in my company have just created separate projects in Luntbuild for their branches, but I feel like that might not be the ideal solution.

So, to reiterate, I want to build this branch continuously.  If I just add a second module to the current setup, it tries to build both trunk and the branch together.  I want them build separately.

Thanks for any insight!

**EDIT**: The bounty is about to end, and still no answers.  I have worked around the original problem by creating a new project in LB, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I've never used Luntbuild before, continuous integration does interest me. I found the following link and hope it is of use to you: http://osdir.com/ml/java.luntbuild.user/2007-10/msg00088.html

Please drop a comment on this if it does work, I am rather curious to see what the final solution is. Good luck!

Comment: I think this might work! Thanks! I accepted the answer before trying it to be sure you get the bounty, but I will report back with an update.